# trying to get the lastest entry on a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using this code to make the top 10 most common names on my dataframe

```
df_faces_nombre = df_faces.groupby(["Nombre"])

top_names = df_faces_nombre.count().sort_values(by=['foto'], ascending=False).iloc[0:10]["foto"].index

for name in top_names:
     fotos = df_faces_nombre.get_group(name)["foto"]
     os.mkdir(TOP_DATA + name)
     for foto in fotos:
         if type(foto) == str and os.path.exists(DATA_DIR+foto):
            try:
                copyfile(DATA_DIR+foto, TOP_DATA + name + '/' + foto)
            except:
                print(foto)
```

Now I'm trying to make a new one to sort the 10 less common names, I thought using something similar in this way

```
low_names = df_faces_nombre.count().sort_values(by=['foto'], ascending=True).iloc[0:100]["foto"].index

for name in low_names:
     fotos = df_faces_nombre.get_group(name)["foto"]
     os.mkdir(LOWER_DATA + name)
     for foto in fotos:
         if type(foto) == str and os.path.exists(DATA_DIR+foto):
            try:
                copyfile(DATA_DIR+foto, LOWER_DATA + name + '/' + foto)
            except:
                print(foto)
```

The problem here is that the second code only copy the folders and not the pictures (sad face) i was hoping that you can help me to solve this, thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, I don't get it: are you able to select the correct files but not to copy them?

Comment: jeje srry solved by myself the problemas was that the first entries does not have any picture, in the 120'th it start to copy the pics

Comment: if you did solve it could you close this?

Comment: srry dont know how to do it, should i answer my own question? or delet the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved there were a lot of names w/o pictures the code works well